# What is this part on the Me 262?

Tags: feature-identification, radar, wwii

I have seen this part on a me 262 model kit but I don't know what it is... I've make some research on it but I find nothing! Maybe it can be radar, or a weapon? Do you know what is this? And also its function?[image: ??]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are [Werfer-Granate 21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werfer-Granate_21) rocket launchers -

> The Werfer-Granate 21 rocket launcher, also known as the BR 21 (the
> "BR" standing for Bordrakete) in official Luftwaffe manuals, was a
> weapon used by the German Luftwaffe during World War II and was the
> first on-board rocket placed into service by the Luftwaffe, first
> introduced in mid 1943.

On the Me262 they were mounted one each side of the nosegear well.

This is the exact aircraft your model is based on -
[image: Messerschmitt Me262A-1a]

> Messerschmitt Me262A-1a 'Green 3' of the *Geschwaderstab* [headquarters unit] of JG 7 prepared
> to move off across the concrete surface at Brandenburg-Briest in
> February or early March 1945. The aircraft, finished in a relatively
> rare application of streaked horizontal lines, **has been fitted with a
> pair of 21cm WGr air-to-air mortar tubes** visible beneath the fuselage
> aft of the nose wheel. ([source](http://luftwaffelovers.blogspot.com/2016/04/anti-bomber-pilots-in-defense-of-reich_17.html))